# Palindrome challenge

Tags: javascript

**

- Who can see why the array is not being reversed?

**

Longest Palindrome
Find the length of the longest substring in the given string s that is the same in reverse.

As an example, if the input was “I like racecars that go fast”, the substring (racecar) length would be 7.

If the length of the input string is 0, the return value must be 0.

```
Example:
"a" -> 1 
"aab" -> 2  
"abcde" -> 1
"zzbaabcd" -> 4
"" -> 0
longestPalindrome=function(s){
  let arr = s.split("")
  let counter = 0
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    let newarr = arr.slice(0,i)
    if(newarr === newarr.reverse()){
      console.log(newarr.reverse())
      counter += 1
    } else if(newarr !== newarr.reverse()){
      return counter
    }
  }
  return counter
}
```

Comment: You can't use `===` to compare arrays.

Comment: How can I solve this then?

Comment: your logic is wrong as well

Comment: Ok please elaborate thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [just googling it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindrome-substring-set-1/) instead?

Comment: Yes but I would like to understand what's wrong with my code. Why is the logic wrong?

Comment: take an example `"baa"` and think what your algorithm will return and what is the correct answer.

Comment: Perhaps this pseudocode sample will help. Take a five-letter string "aabcb". Your current algorithm checks a, aa, aab, aabc, and aabcb. That's five arrays/strings it checks for palindrome and length. Off the top of my head, your code _should_ check about fifteen arrays/strings: a, aa, aab, aabc, aabcb, a, ab, abc, abcb, b, bc, bcb, c, cb, and b. Once you are checking all the possibilities, and I don't think you are right now, THEN you'll want to find a way besides === to compare two arrays. I believe @MdJohirulIslam is trying to help you move in that direction also.